# how to add more than one custom section to WordPress Theme Customizer

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a very hard time adding more than one section to the Theme Customizer in WordPress 4.0. My functions.php is here:

http://pastebin.com/uQRh46K4

I want to be able to change the header and footer background color, which works fine and shows in the theme customizer. But the custom colors for the entry title, h3 and widget title don't show in the customizer. I checked my syntax and it appears to be fine. I'm a newbie and I'm stumped! Please help me out!

Comment: I've solved my current problem; I just added the controls to the colors section. But I would still like to know how to add more than one section and have it work.

Comment: Two observations: you should post the code here instead of pastebin; and post only the relevant part, we don't need to see widgets or comments, that only makes difficult to focus on the customizer.

Comment: Thank you, I will bear that in mind next time. I did figure it out; I just needed practice. :)